# How do I use url_for calling @app.route('/')?

Tags: flask

I've a route like this:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/upload')
def upload():
    if someCondition():
        return redirect(url_for(''))
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

and a section of `upload.html` template:

```
<a class="link toolbar-nav-links" href="{{ url_for('') }}">Home</a>
```

When I attempt to launch the web page, I get `BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint ''. Did you mean 'upload' instead?`

When I change to `url_for('upload')`, I can successfully load the page and the links work, but when I click on Home, I get `192.168.1.1:5000/upload` in the browser URL bar.

How do I implement `url_for()` so that when I click on the Home link, I would load `192.168.1.1:5000/` instead of `192.168.1.1:5000/upload`?

Comment: `return redirect('/')` will do the job. Since you declared both routes on the same function, it's up to `url_for` to decide which one to take. You could look into that.

Comment: @Kruspe So there is no way to redirect to '/' using `url_for()`? What if `@app.route('/')` and `@app.route('upload')` are to different functions? Also, can I clarify: if `@app.route('/abc')` is routed to `def()` should I write `url_for('abc')` or `url_for('def')`?

Comment: Go for the function name. `url_for('def')` will result in `/abc`